# Difftime slow with data.table IDate in R

Tags: r, data.table, datediff

Reading `?IDate` it seemed like a good idea to convert my character variables to integer dates in my largish data table. Who does not want fast sorting and grouping?

The `IDate` help clearly mentions the functionality is still experimental, so my question is more feedback than complaint.

Why is it that calculating a time difference for the integer date (IDate) class variable takes so much longer than other date class variables, or integers?

```
# Example data
require(data.table)
n <- 1e7
dt <- data.table(x1 = sample(1000:2000, n, replace=TRUE),
                 x2 = sample(1000:2000, n, replace=TRUE))

# Add date variables.
dt[, date1 := as.Date(x1, origin="1990-01-01")]
dt[, date2 := as.Date(x2, origin="1990-01-01")]

# Add integer-dates.
dt[, idate1 := as.IDate(date1)]
dt[, idate2 := as.IDate(date2)]

# Add POSIXct dates.
dt[, posix1 := as.POSIXct(date1)]
dt[, posix2 := as.POSIXct(date2)][]

# Check variable classes.
sapply(dt[, list(x1, date1, idate1, posix1)], class)
```

Gives

```
$x1
[1] "integer"

$date1
[1] "Date"

$idate1
[1] "IDate" "Date" 

$posix1
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

All good.

Now let's find out how long it takes to compute the difference for each class.

```
# Compute date diffs.
system.time(dt[, x.diff := x1 - x2])
user  system elapsed 
0.07    0.00    0.06

system.time(dt[, date.diff := date1 - date2])
user  system elapsed 
0.39    0.13    0.51

system.time(dt[, idate.diff := idate1 - idate2])
user  system elapsed 
6.21    0.67    6.91 

system.time(dt[, posix.diff := posix1 - posix2]) # diff in seconds
user  system elapsed 
0.20    0.09    0.30
```

The IDate class is at least an order of ten slower than the rest, surprising as it's supposed to be stored as an integer?

```
# Check results are identical.
identical(dt[, date1], dt[, idate1])
[1] TRUE
```

Date and IDate results are identical. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of the why, but you can "fix" it by casting IDate into integer. I also don't know why that fixes it. I know this isn't an answer, but more like a follow-up observation:

```
> system.time(dt[, idate.diff := idate1 - idate2])
   user  system elapsed 
   4.78    0.44    5.25 
> head(dt$idate.diff)
Time differences in days
[1] -620 -491  634  151  110 -338
> system.time(dt[, idate.int.diff := as.integer(idate1) - as.integer(idate2)])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.06    0.01    0.08 
> head(dt$idate.int.diff)
[1] -620 -491  634  151  110 -338
```

Comment: That's a good observation. For now I'm sticking to `POSIXct`. Do you reckon this is a bug in `IDate`?

Comment: I'll check the [data.table issue list](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) later and see if there's anything about it.